# Disabling jquery keypress when in input or textarea fields

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to fire off an event when a certain key is pressed. It works fine with this code:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){ 
    switch(e.which){ 
            case 96:$("a.quicklinks").trigger('click'); 
            break; 
    }
```

But, if the user is in a form field, I'd like to disable this behavior. How do I test whether the user is typing in a form field to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) { 
    if ($(e.target).is('input, textarea')) {
        // event invoked from input or textarea
    }
    ...        
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can set a global var

```
var disable_keyevents = false;
$('textarea,input')
    .focus(function() { disable_keyevents = true })
    .blur(function() { disable_keyevents = true; });
```

then you just check the value of disable_keyevents in the $(document).keypress event before the switch.

Answer (score 1):

This code will trigger when the user presses ASCII character #96 inside your form - you may use this to disable / modify the "default code" for this keypress.

```
$('#my_form_field').live('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 96) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Do stuff.
    }
});
```